# Use import in jsx file play framework

Tags: scala, reactjs, jsx

I am using Play Framework 2.5 and ReactJS and I would like to be able to use `import`in my `.jsx` files but it seems like I am not allowed to do it because it throws an error in the javascript console saying that import is not recognized.

I added the [sbt-reactjs](https://github.com/dispalt/sbt-reactjs) to my build.sbt and I see that ReactJS compiles files each time they are changed, however I still have this `import`error.

It can be really problematic as my application will grow because the components will become bigger and for example I would like to divide my navbar and to have `Nav.js`and `NavItem.js` and I want to be able to call any component I have created in any `*.js` file of my application.

I have heard about babel that could transpile my code in pure javascript code but I would like to have more information about it, more precisely, can it works with Play (ie. will the files be transpiled during the `assets` command ?).

So my question is: Can I use the `import` with only the libs I have installed or do I have to add something else to my build.sbt ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, from searching on the net, there seems there are lot of ways of doing it. I also ran into same problem. The best example I found was to use webpack for building the jsx files. The following git repo has all u need.

https://github.com/nouhoum/play-react-webpack